# Changes to leaflet Settings not working

Tags: 7

I am unable to alter a settings of a leaflet map generated by a view using the method described here in a custom module. https://www.drupal.org/node/1883788

Using the code below in my custom module does not work.

```
  function MYMODULE_leaflet_map_info_alter(&$map_info) {
      $map_info['esri-world-street-map']['settings']['scrollWheelZoom'] = TRUE;
      $map_info['esri-world-topo-map']['settings']['scrollWheelZoom'] = TRUE;
  }
```

Where MYMODULE is the name of my module.

Someone else had this same issue and we have been talking trying to solve the issue. https://www.drupal.org/node/2831593

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: Yup. Module had been there for a week. Someone else has this same problem too on the forums.

Comment: Could you update your Question with a link to the forum topic?

Comment: Gee that was embarrassing https://www.drupal.org/node/2831593

Comment: Maybe it is a leaflet.markercluster version issue?

Comment: Maybe. I am using the latest version. Ill try an older one...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is crossposted as a bug report in the module's issue queue.  DA is not the place for bug reports; issue queues are the proper place and cross-posts are counter-productive.

Comment: Yes but it has gotten responses here and none on the forum. So it is productive because this bounty has gotten it a response while in the forum it was not seen.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in your question can never work: you need, at least, change the function name from "`MYMODULE_leaflet_map_info_alter`" to the actual name of your module.

PS: debugging is the art of taking away all possible reasons why something doesn't work as expected. This is for sure 1 of the possible reasons ...

Comment: i didn't have enough rep to leave a comment :(

Comment: Since you didn't "object" my edit in any way (yet), I assume you're ok with my edit ...

Comment: I changed the hook name to the module, this is just example code.  This is the issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2831593

Comment: Using MYMODULE or MYTHEME in questions and answers here is pretty standard to make something generic.  It's used hundreds, if not, thousands of times in posts on DA.